# Attempt to violate lock task mode

Tags: android

I have ActivityA, ActivityB, BaseActivity and CloseActivity. Below is my code.

```
public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        startLockTask();
   }

 public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.languageBtn:
             startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
        default:
             break;
        }
  }
   protected void onDestroy() {
        stopLockTask();
    }

}

public class ActivityB extends BaseActivity {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
      setContentView();  
   }  

  public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.someBtn:
                clodeDialog();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
       setContentView();
   }

   clodeDialog(){
      clodeDialog(null);
   }

   clodeDialog(Intent broadcastIntent){      
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CloseActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(CloseActivity.BROADCAST_INTENT_EXTRA, broadcastIntent);        
        startActivity(intent);
   }

}
```

From here I am launching CloseActivity. But I am getting below message 
startActivityUnchecked: Attempt to violate Lock Task Mode. Not able to launch CloseActivity. What is the cause.

Comment: It seems that `startLockTask();` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` don't go together well because the task locking is supposed to *prevent* any new tasks...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But it is working on L not in android O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `stopLockTask` inside clodeDialog method before calling `startActivity` .

```
clodeDialog(Intent broadcastIntent){      
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CloseActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(CloseActivity.BROADCAST_INTENT_EXTRA, broadcastIntent); 
        stopLockTask       
        startActivity(intent);
   }
```

By This I resolved the issue.